# Override inline colorbox JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox, inline-code

I am working on a site where the html cannot be modified, and need to override some inline onclick code for colorbox modal content.

Such as:

```
<span data-colorbox-theme="white" data-colorbox-options="{&quot;href&quot;:&quot;#joinTheClub-moreDetails&quot;, &quot;inline&quot;:true, &quot;iframe&quot;:false, &quot;width&quot;:&quot;430&quot;, &quot;height&quot;:&quot;340&quot;, &quot;scrolling&quot;:false}" class="colorboxWindow more-details cboxElement">More details</span>
```

Each link across the site has different widths and heights which I would like to override in the head (which I do have access to) for a standard percentage width and height (different values for both desktop and mobile views).

My JQuery is fairly rudimentary and google hasn't yet yielded any definitive answers.

How should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

after adding or changing any css proprety just add `!important` to it it will NOT be ovrrided by jquery or any exemple :

```
.someclass{
width:150px !important;
}
```

this will set the width of any object with the class `someclass` to 150 and prevent any other style to ovrride it(jquery styles,browser styles,another predefined styles in the site.....).

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, yes I know throwing in !important rules is an option, but colorbox calculates widths of several divs contained within the wrapper (which I could give width: 100%!important), but this isn't great on browser resize.

I was hoping to write a JQuery function that overrides that inline stuff!

Comment: could you please be more clear so i can help you ? :)

Comment: I would like to override the inline JQuery rather than trying to override lots of JQuery-generated CSS rules.

This would be a global rule in the header, allowing the inline html to retain references to iframes but keeping width, height and position consistent

Comment: So just to provide a bit more detail:

Putting important rules on the height doesnt really work because some overlays are iframes and some are not. Some have inline height parameters defined and some do not. This also needs to be reactive / responsive and resizing the browser causes the height to remain fixed. 

What I need to do is have a JQuery function that always overrides any inline parameters. What is the correct method to do that? I cannot simply strip all the inline functions out because in some cases they include the url.